# Styling checkboxes that are even children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a whole bunch of checkboxes and want to style all the ones that are even children i.e 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th.

I have tried doing the following but to no avail.

```
.basic li > div .choices input[type="checkbox"] {
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
    float:left;
    border:0 none;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0;
}

.basic li > div .choices input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(2n-1) {
    margin:0px 0px 0px 60px;
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? CSS3 selector support is not 100%. Also could you post your markup

Comment: `:nth-child(2n-1)` will give you odds... 2 x 1 - 1 = *1*, 2 x 2 - 1 = *3*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:nth-child(even)` or `:nth-child(2n+0)` (any calculation resulting in an even integer) according to:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: @BoltClock: True, they are the same. I wanted to be consistent with W3, though they note that these are the same further down the page.